# How to get full hierarchy with recursive CTE in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, recursion

**Table:**

```
+-----+------------+-------------+
| Id  | DocumentNo | ParentCCID  |
+-----+------------+-------------+
|  10 | CC001      | NULL        |
|  20 | CC002      | CC001       |
|  33 | CC003      | CC002       |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

Value passed to the query: `CC002`

**Expected Output:**

```
CC003
CC002
CC001
```

**The following query only gets you the records that are placed higher in the hierarchy :**

```
;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT Id,
            documentno,
            DocumentTypeID,
            ParentCCID
        FROM basicdetails
        WHERE DocumentNo = 'CC#000056'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT R.Id,
            R.DocumentNo,
            R.DocumentTypeID,
            R.ParentCCID
        FROM basicdetails R
        JOIN cte P ON P.ParentCCID = R.DocumentNo
        )

SELECT Id,
    documentno,     
    ParentCCID
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Note: DocumentNo is unique primary key. ParentCCID could have null values if there is no parent record.

```
create table basicdetails
  (
    id int identity,
    documentno varchar(30),
    parentccid varchar(30)
  )
    insert into basicdetails values('CC001', null)
    insert into basicdetails values('CC002', 'CC001')
    insert into basicdetails values('CC003', 'CC002')
    insert into basicdetails values('CC004', 'CC003')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.

```
;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT Id,
            documentno,
            DocumentTypeID,
            ParentCCID
        FROM basicdetails
        WHERE DocumentNo = 'CC02'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT R.Id,
            R.DocumentNo,
            R.DocumentTypeID,
            R.ParentCCID
        FROM basicdetails R
        JOIN cte P ON P.ParentCCID = R.DocumentNo
        ),

      cte2 AS (
        SELECT Id,
            documentno,
            DocumentTypeID,
            ParentCCID
        FROM basicdetails
        WHERE DocumentNo = 'CC002'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT R.Id,
            R.DocumentNo,
            R.DocumentTypeID,
            R.ParentCCID
        FROM basicdetails R
        JOIN cte2 P ON P.DocumentNo = R.ParentCCID
        )


SELECT Id,
    documentno,
    DocumentTypeID,
    ParentCCID
FROM cte     

 union   

SELECT Id,
    documentno,
    DocumentTypeID,
    ParentCCID
FROM cte2
```

Though I am not sure if this is the best way. It does work. I just had to reverse 
`JOIN cte P ON P.ParentCCID = R.DocumentNo` and perform `UNION`